# Range.find not working with excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with range.find method in excel VBA.

I have two sheets.
Sheet A has a format as follows (months are irregular intervals):

```
Dec-1997
Dec-1999
Dec-2000
Dec-2001
Dec-2002
Dec-2003
Dec-2004
Dec-2005
Dec-2006
Mar-2007
Dec-2007
Dec-2008
Dec-2009
Dec-2010
Dec-2011(a)
Dec-2013
Dec-2014
```

Sheet B has a column A where dates are laid out in regular quarterly intervals like below.

```
Jun-2011
Sep-2011
Dec-2011
Mar-2012
Jun-2012
Sep-2012
Dec-2012
Mar-2013
Jun-2013
Sep-2013
Dec-2013
Mar-2014
Jun-2014
Sep-2014
Dec-2014
```

I want my VBA code to iterate through each item in sheet A and find the associated row number in sheet B.

Here's the snippet from my code:

```
Sub sSearch(arr As Variant, j As Integer, rngSearch As Range, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim wsWrite As Worksheet
    Set wsWrite = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Sheet B
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim intRows As Integer
    Dim rngRow As Range
    Dim strDate As String

    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        Set rngResult = rngSearch.Find(arr(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
        intRows = rngResult.End(xlDown).Row - rngResult.Row ' determine number of rows in Sheet A
        For k = 1 To intRows '
            strDate = Left(rngResult.Offset(k).Text, 9)
            set rngRow = wsWrite.Range("A:A").Find(What:=strDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
            wsWrite.Cells(intRow, i + j).Value = arr(i)
            wsWrite.Cells(intRow, i + j).Value = _
                ws.Cells( _
                rngResult.End(xlDown).Row, _
                rngResult.End(xlToRight).Column).Value
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

I get an error on the following line

```
set rngRow = wsWrite.Range("A:A").Find(What:=strDate, LookIn:=xlValues)
```

I tried everything I could think of including looking through microsoft documentation, searching on here but no luck.
rngRow returns nothing even though I can see that the value stored in strDate is a value in cell A2 of that sheet. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Chinwobble,
what will the macro do when a value is found?

Comment: It's hard to fix without knowing the actual value of the cells.  Since it may be a real date formatted as custom format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `array(i)` value to date -> `CDate(arr(i))`. New Find line looks like this:

`Set rngRow = wsWrite.Range("A:B").Find(What:=CDate(arr(i)), LookIn:=xlFormulas)`

Without `CDate(arr(i))` you can't find the data, you can manually test in excel, only with a search like `"Dec-00"` excel finds something

Check if date or string:

```
If IsDate(Arr(i)) Then
value_to_lookup = CDate(Arr(i))
Else
value_to_lookup = Arr(i)
End If
Set rngRow = Range("A:b").Find(What:=value_to_lookup, LookIn:=xlFormulas)
```

Comment: But is the data inside the cell really a date? Having something like `Dec-2011(a)` tells me that the values are not numerical (just strings). But still a good assumption... We probably need more informations about that from @Chinwobble

Comment: Well I copied and pasted his values in an excel file, they are dates (number of days since 1900 until today) not string values

Comment: but you do not know if he has copy/pasted it. select the range and set it to "text". then paste it again ;) still: how much is "Dec-2011(a)"?

Comment: @Dirk Riehcel, the data is in a date format. However the cell containing the text "Dec-2011(a)" is a string (the text and value property of that cell is "Dec-2011(a)".
How can is it possible to manage this case? Do I need to convert the date variables to strings in the VBA code?

Comment: Test is value is date then convert, else use initial value (string). Please see my initial answer for the new code

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't something like this be faster:

```
Function getRow(str As String, rng As Range) As Long
str = Left (str, 10)
getRow = Application.Match(str, rng, 0)
End Function
```

This will give the row as long which can be used to set a range...

Or to get the cell as ref:

```
Function getCell(str As String, rng As Range) As Range
str = Left (str, 10)
Set getCell = rng(1).Offset(Application.Match(str, rng, 0) - 1)
End Function
```

Asuming you use 1 column to look at (for both cases)